# TypeError: state.update is not a function faced with react-planner package

Tags: reactjs

I wanted to create a project by using react-planner package and faced the problem as I was trying to implement react-planner. That is, I get "TypeError: state.update is not a function" and this is the code I am using:

```
import { Map } from "immutable";
import {
  Models as PlannerModels,
  reducer as PlannerReducer,
} from "react-planner";

const initialState = {
  defaultState: {},
};

let AppState = Map({
  "react-planner": new PlannerModels.State(),
});

let plannerReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  state = state || AppState;
  state = state.update("react-planner", (plannerState) =>
    PlannerReducer(plannerState, action)
  );
  return state;
};
export default plannerReducer;
```

Comment: well yes it isn't a function? `initialState = { }` and then `state = initialState` so `state = { }` which is an object, not a function. where do you define `update` function?

Comment: @RedBaron, thank you for your kind comments, update function comes from immutable.js library